# Spring Google calendar push notification register a webhook url with access token

Tags: java, spring, rest, google-calendar-api

I have a spring (with apache wicket) application, and have an API for registering a webhook for calendar events. It is working fine when the API called is publicly accessible.

The problem now is we need to secure this API and it would need an access token for the API call.

My problem is, I cannot find a sample of the payload where the access token is passed to use when calling the API (`myApiUrl`).

Below are snippets of the working API call (unsecured/public).

```
        String accessToken = getGoogleAccessToken();

        ...

        String format = "{ \"id\": \"%s\", \"type\": \"%s\", \"expiration\": %d, \"address\": \"%s\" }";
        String payload = String.format(format, id, _TYPE_WEBHOOK, expiryEpoch, myApiUrl);

        HttpHeaders header = new HttpHeaders();
        header.set("Content-Type", "application/json");
        header.set("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);

        ...
```

How will I be able to pass an access token to be used when push notification calls `myApiUrl`. Please assume that the access token validity is long (hours/day) and still valids until the next api call.

I am looking for examples on how to insert/add the access token in the payload.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you consider using a service account?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by service account, `accessToken` from `getGoogleAccessToken()` is good... I just need to pass another string value to add in my API's header call. Those values from `payload` reflects in my APIs header like `id, type, expiration, address`... I am guessing now that if I add another value for `clientInfo`, I can get this value in the header like the other values (id, type, address, etc). Just guessing though

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your question correctly. Do you want to know how to fetch events from Google Calendar? Are you familiar with the Google Calendar API quickstart that shows you how you can communicate with the calendar with the Google API methods?  https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/java